# MySQL Query using a Foreign Key to return Names in Ordered Format

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query related to fetching records from the combination of 2 tables in a way that the returned result will be fetched using the ORDER by clause with the help of foreign key.

I have two tables named **users** and **orders**.

**Table:** users

```
id  name
1   John
2   Doe
```

**Table:** orders

```
id  user_id    for
1   2          cake
2   1          shake
2   2          milk
```

In table:orders, **user_id** is foreign key representing id in table:users.

**Question:**

I want to extract the records from table:orders but the ORDER should be based on name of users.

**Desired Results:**

```
user_id    for
2          cake
2          milk
1          shake
```

**Note:** Here user_id with 2 is showing before user id with 1. This is because the name **Doe** should be shown before the name **John** because of order by.

**What I have done right now:**

I have no idea about MySQL joins. By searching this thing on the internet i did not find a way how i will achieve this thing. I have written a query but it will not fetch such record but have no idea what should i do to make it work exactly like what i want to.

```
SELECT * FROM orders ORDER BY user_id
```

It will fetch the records according to the order of user_id but not with name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are right join both tables is the simplest way to achieve that and you can show the names also, as you have them joined anyway

> ```
> CREATE TABLE orders (
>   `id` INTEGER,
>   `user_id` INTEGER,
>   `for` VARCHAR(5)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO orders
>   (`id`, `user_id`, `for`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', '2', 'cake'),
>   ('2', '1', 'shake'),
>   ('2', '2', 'milk');
>
> CREATE TABLE users (
>   `id` INTEGER,
>   `name` VARCHAR(4)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO users
>   (`id`, `name`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', 'John'),
>   ('2', 'Doe');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT o.`user_id`, o.`for` FROM orders o INNER JOIN users u ON u.id = o.user_id  ORDER BY u.name
> ```
>
> ```
> user_id | for  
> ------: | :----
>       2 | cake 
>       2 | milk 
>       1 | shake
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9a4c0543fca437fae63f6d0dbb32b955)*

Comment: Perfect Sir. If i want to extract all columns then i have to write o. with each or there is another way ?

Comment: Got it Sir. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You can get your desired results by join orders table and users table by simply using below query.

```
SELECT user_id, for FROM orders, users where user_id = id ORDER BY name;
```

Using where condition, we match corresponding rows where `user_id` in orders table equals `id` in users table. By using `ORDER BY` for `name` column in users table, rows will be sorted in ascending order. Here `user_id` and `for` columns in orders table will be show as final result.

Here I haven't use `users.id` or `orders.user_id` because they are in different formats. If you use same format for columns, you need to use above syntax.

Comment: comma separated tables aren't used any more, they make essential cross joins that you have to filter later

Comment: Thank You @nbk I''ll look into that.